# How to converting in to time?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I am trying to convert to time from a string 
My string are like this "11:45 AM" or "03:19 PM" and i am using

```
dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("11:45 AM", "H:mm tt",
                                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Then it is getting converted but when i am passing

```
DateTime.ParseExact("3:19 PM", "H:mm tt", 
                     System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString();
```

Getting error as

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

I cant understand why it is happening  any one have idea then please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `h` instead of `H`. `H` is for the 24hr fromat, `h` for the 12hr format.

```
DateTime.ParseExact("9:45 PM", "h:mm tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

See the full list of format options [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: yes, Ned,, But the problem is i need to convert 12 hr format to 24 hr format

Comment: @SreerejithSS the format string you pass should be the input format.  The input format is 12-hour format, therefore the format string should use "h" rather than "H".  The result of the conversion has no format; it is a DateTime value.  You can give it a 24-hour format when you convert it back to a string somewhere else.

Comment: @Ned  Thanks For your help, Now i understand where i got wrong

Answer (score 3):

As you want to parse the 12 hr format and convert it to the 24 hr format then you can just use this

```
string dt = DateTime.ParseExact("3:19 PM", "h:mm tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("HH:mm");;
```

Comment: your code works but I want to get 24 hr format thats y given 'H'

Comment: @SreerejithSS updated the post. Please use the updated code and let me  know if it solves your problem

Comment: @SreerejithSS this may work, but it is less efficient than Ned Stoyanov's answer, which I think is also correct.  The format string has to reflect the input format, but 24 hour format is your output format.

Comment: @Sachin passing the 24 hour format is pointless since the input is in the 12 h format. The answer should also mention that it's `ToString()` that generates a 24h string and that has nothing to do with parsing

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, none of the answers are *completely* correct.

Ante meridiem and post meridiem belong to the [12-hour clock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock) format. That's why you should *never* use [24-hour clock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock) format specifiers if your string contains one of them.

That's why you need to use `h` or `hh` specifiers, **not** `H` or `HH`. Since your hour part can be with leading zeros, using [`hh` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#hhSpecifier) is the best option for both of your string types.

Using the `hh:mm tt` format will parse your strings successfully.

```
string s = "03:19 PM";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    dt.Dump(); // 29.05.2015 15:19:00
}
```

and

```
string s = "11:45 AM";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    dt.Dump(); // 29.05.2015 11:45:00
}
```

Also, you mentioned the `3:19 PM` string in your code example. Since the hour part is single digit, you need to use the `h:mm tt` format in that case.

Comment: Your last paragraph, which is correct, contradicts the third paragraph, which is incorrect.

Comment: @phoog No, it does not.OP mentioned in his explanation as his/her strings are `11:45 AM` and `03:19 PM`. But his/her used `3:19 PM` string in his second code example. In first two string, using `hh` format specifier is the best option, but this specifier won't work for `3:19 PM` string because his hour part does not have a leading zero. If there are third different _kind_ formatted string, using [`DateTime.ParseExact` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes string array as a parameter is the best option. But OP have never mentioned that.

Comment: The `hh` specifier works for two-digit hours only.  The `h` specifier works for one-digit and two-digit hours.  Therefore, there's no need to use the overload that takes a string array; the specifier should just be `h:mm tt`.

Comment: @phoog Even `h:mm tt` will parse `03:19 PM` successfully, you should **not** use it. That will break your strings _stability_ that you want to parse them to `DateTime`. Look at this way; When you try you get hour part of a `DateTime` value _with_ leading zero, you will use `hh` specifier, right? If so, why you try to use `h` specifier when you parse this hour part with leading zero? That doesn't make sense, right? Always, **always** use the best fitted format specifiers, not just _will parse it anyway_ specifiers. Of course these are just my opinion.

Comment: But if you know your input is mixed (some hours with leading zeros, some with just a single digit), why would you use the less-efficient overload that takes a string array?  It's just more typing and more processor cycles for the same outcome.

Comment: @phoog I think knowing _exact_ format of the input and using the proper format(s) is more important than typing a little bit more and more  processor cycles

Comment: But you are imputing a properness to the format string that does not exist.  There is no format string that rejects leading-zero hours.  Therefore, there is no format string that you could include in the array as an explicit indication that leading-zero hours are allowable in the input.

Answer (score -1):

Invariant culture requires two-digit hours.

Comment: Code posted by Sachin works just fine with InvariantCulture :o

Comment: That works but I need to get the time in 24 hr format

Comment: @SreerejithSS the time is only in 24-hour format when you convert it to a string.  The DateTime type has no particular format; in memory it is stored as a 64-bit integer.

Comment: The culture places no limits on which *format* to use for parsing. It affects only how culture-specific text is parsed, eg `AM/PM` or whether to use `\` for the date separator or `.` (eg for German cultures)